# How to read image data/get binary data from image in javascript/jquery without any File API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, binary

I'm using IE8 so any File API are not available for me. I wanna be able to read image data/ get its binary data so that I can pass it to my webservice which creates an image.

This is my html and javascript code:

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn"/>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
                    var fileStream = $("#file").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ,
                        dataType: "image/gif",
                        url: "http://localhost/WebServices/Upload.asmx/ByteArrayToImage",
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        success: function () {
                            alert('yes');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('bouh');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
   </script>
```

I know that my code above does not work because the $("#file").val() will only give me a fake path. That is why I need to know how to get binary data.

My webservice code:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bArray)
        {
            if (bArray == null)
                return null;

            System.Drawing.Image newImage;

            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bArray, 0, bArray.Length))
                {
                    ms.Write(bArray, 0, bArray.Length);
                    newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                newImage = null;

                //Log an error here
            }


            return newImage;
        }
```

Please help, I've been looking for answers for days.. THANK YOU!

*note: i removed the data field blank above on purpose because i don't know how to pass binary data of image to webservice